Question about a grammar who generates $(0+1)^*$
On a test from my Automata theory class of last year, I have seen an excercise that gives the free context grammar $G$ with the following rules:
$$S \rightarrow 0S1 | S0 | 1S | \varepsilon$$
and asks about what languages generates. In the solutions, it says that it is $(0+1)^*$ , but I do not see why.
I have tried to see it by induction: it is clear that $w \in (0+1)^*$ of length $1$ belongs to $L(G)$, so given $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\{ w \in  (0+1)^* : |w| = n \} \subset L(G)$, a word $w' \in (0+1)^*, |w| = n+1$ is of the form $\{0w, 1w, w0, w1\}$ with $w \in (0+1)^*, |w|=n$ . It is clear that $w0$ and $1w$ can be generated from the Induction hypothesis and the rules of the grammar, but I do not see how to generate $0w$ and $w1$, so any possible help would be appreciated.

We can prove this using mathematical induction. For base case, it is easy to see that $S$ can generate $\varepsilon, 0, 1, 00, 11, 01, 10$. Now we assume $S$ can generate any binary string on $0$s and $1$s of length up to $k \ge 0$ (strong induction hypothesis). We now need to prove that we can generate any binary string of length $k+1$.
Consider a $k+1$-length string, $\omega$. If $\omega$ starts with a $1$, we can first apply the rule $S \rightarrow 1S$ and then generate the remaining $k$ length from new $S$. The same holds if the string ends with a $0$ and we start with $S \rightarrow S0$. If both of this does not hold, then $\omega$ is of the form $0x1$. Note that $x$ is a binary string on length $k-1$. So in this case, we start with $S \rightarrow 0S1$, and then we can generate any $k-1$-length string $x$ (due to the strong induction hypothesis).
